# System of Equations: any solutions at all?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations

I am looking for any complex number solutions to the system of equations:

$$\begin{align}
|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2&=\frac13
\\ \bar{a}b+a\bar{c}+\bar{b}c&=\frac16 (2+\sqrt{3}i).
\end{align}$$

Note I put inequality in the tags as I imagine it is an inequality that shows that this has no solutions (as I suspect is the case).

This is connected to my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320060/positive-elements-of-mathbbcg-as-functionals-versus-as-elements-of-the-c)... I have found that $(4,1,1)/6$ and $\mu=(2,2+\sqrt{3}i,2-\sqrt{3}i)/6$ are square roots of $(2,1,1)/4$ in $(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{Z}_3,\star)$ but am trying to understand why $\mu$ is not positive in the C*-algebra when, for example, $(14,-6+5i,-6-5i)$ is.

Comment: Does the bar represent conjugate? i.e., $\bar{a} \times b$ ?

Comment: @Mann yes... "complex number solutions".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz, we must have$$\left(|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2 \right) \left(|\overline{c}|^2+|\overline{a}|^2+|\overline{b}|^2 \right) \ge \left| a\overline c + b\overline a + c\overline b\right|^2$$
$$\implies \frac19 \ge \frac1{36}|2+\sqrt3 \; i|^2 = \frac7{4\cdot9}$$
which is obviously not possible...

Comment: $\left(|a|\left|\overline{c}\right|+|b||\overline{a}|+|c| |\overline{b}| \right)^2\neq \left| a\overline c + b\overline a + c\overline b\right|^2$, unless $a,b,c$ are positive reals ([WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C+a*%28conjugate%5Bc%5D%29+%2B+b*%28conjugate%5Ba%5D%29+%2B+c*%28conjugate%5Bb%5D%29%7C%5E2+-+%28%7Ca%7C*%7Cconjugate%5Bc%5D%7C%2B%7Cb%7C*%7Cconjugate%5Ba%5D%7C%2B%7Cc%7C*%7Cconjugate%5Bb%5D%7C%29%5E2)).

Comment: @user26486 and why is that relevant?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz says: $\left(|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2 \right) \left(|\overline{c}|^2+|\overline{a}|^2+|\overline{b}|^2 \right) \ge \left(|a|\left|\overline{c}\right|+|b||\overline{a}|+|c| |\overline{b}| \right)^2$

Comment: @user26486 Check https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy-Schwarz_Inequality/Complex_Numbers for the statement and proof as applied to Complex numbers. I am sure there are more references.  The version you have posted is actually CS inequality for the moduli - which are all real numbers.

Comment: Thank you...that helps a lot..,

Comment: Is it true that $\displaystyle{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^3\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|^3\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |z_i|^3\right)\ge \left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_iz_i\right|^3}$ like it is in the real number version ([Hölder's Inequality](https://hcmop.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/holders-inequality/))?

Comment: @macavity when do I have equality here? Sorry for asking you to hold my hand on this!

Comment: @JpMcCarthy For equality, $(a, b, c)$ and $(\overline c, \overline a, \overline b)$ must be scalar multiples.  Here of course the scalar can be a complex number.

Comment: @user26486 There are almost exact analogues of Holder's inequality, Minkowski etc. in complex numbers. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality#Counting_measure